# Scaling data in a topic?

Tags: ros, remapping, ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have a node (that I didn't write) publishing an Int32 value `data` between 0 and 1. Is it possible to scale `data` so it's between 0 and 10 instead of 0 and 1? Ideally, I'm wondering if this can be done in a launch file, though I'm not sure.

Something like:

`<remap from="/data" to="/data" * 10 />`

if you see what I mean

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326794/scaling-data-in-a-topic?/) by [gerhmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41972/gerhmi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Let's say I have a node (that I didn't write) publishing an Int32 value `data` between 0 and 1. Is it possible to scale `data` so it's between 0 and 10 instead of 0 and 1?

I'm going to assume you meant to write:

> Let's say I have a node (that I didn't write) publishing an Int32 value `data` between 0 and 1. Is it possible to scale `data` so it's between 0 and 10 instead of 0 and 1?

As an `Int32` can only encode integer values, so it would only ever be `0` or `1`, nothing in between.

---

This is something that can be done using [topic_tools/transform](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform).

One of the examples on that page does something very similar:

> convert an orientation quaternion to Euler angles:

> ```
> rosrun topic_tools transform /imu/orientation /euler geometry_msgs/Vector3 'tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion([m.x, m.y, m.z, m.w])' --import tf
> ```

So for your specific example, it would probably be something like (haven't tested this):

```
rosrun topic_tools transform /input /output std_msgs/Float32 'm.data * 10.0'
```

As to your question:

> I'm wondering if this can be done in a launch file, though I'm not sure.

> Something like:

> ```
> <remap from="/data" to="/data" * 10 />
> ```

No, that is not possible. `remap`s don't work like that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41972/gerhmi/) on 2019-06-24**:
Thanks! I doubted it could be done as a remap, but you can always hope.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-24**:
PS: note btw that using `std_msgs` msgs is not recommended, as they have almost zero semantics.